# EXIF installed but get error. No module named 'exif'

Tags: python, exif

Trying to get long and lat from images using EXIF. However, when importing the module using this code:

```
from exif import Image
```

I get the error "No module named 'exif'" that the module does not exist. I have installed EXIF using:

```
pip install exif
```

and still get the error when importing the module.

I have also tried EXIFread that has the error "No module named 'exifread'" when importing.
Installing with:

```
pip install exifread
```

and imported with:

```
import exifread
```

I am using Spyder from Anaconda with python3.8.

I have also tried reinstalling Spyder and Anaconda that did not fix it.

Related to the issue, not the code, was using NumPy for table stuff a while ago and had the same issue but installing it fixed the problem, for some reason it won't fix the issue with EXIF.

Comment: Why did you make a new account to repost the [exact same question you posted a couple hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69860999/no-module-named-exif-even-though-it-has-been-installed)?

Comment: Are you sure `pip` is the right way to install packages for Anaconda?  I thought `conda` was used for that.